# Iterate through MYSQL database and replace data in every record in one column

Tags: mysql, loops

I have this VERY inefficient way of updating the phone numbers in my database after cleaning them of all non-digits.

```
$san_phone = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($san_phone)) {
    $row['phone_clean'] = preg_replace('#[^\d]#', '', $row['phone']);
    echo $row['id'] . ' - ' . $row['phone_clean'] . '<br>';

    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET phone = " . $row['phone_clean']  . " WHERE id = " . $row['id']);
}
```

That update part of the loop is causing me to timeout after only about 400 of my 2,400 records.  It's obvious I'm doing something wrong so be gentle when schooling me. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, stop using `mysql_` functions as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions instead.

The method you are using to `UPDATE` your records is inefficient. You should instead create a temporary table, `INSERT` the new records in a single query, and finally run an `UPDATE` query to replace the data.

You can start out with this:

```
$san_phone = mysql_query('SELECT id, phone FROM table');
$insertArray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($san_phone)) {
    $phone_clean = preg_replace('#[^\d]#', '', $row['phone']);
    echo $row['id'] . ' - ' . $row['phone_clean'] . '<br>';

    $insertArray[] = "(" . $row[id] . ", '" . $phone_clean . "')";
}

$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tempTable (id, phone) VALUES ";
$insertQuery = implode(", ", $insertArray);
mysql_query($insertQuery);
```

I've made a quick demo to illustrate this process. `t1` is your original table, and `t2` is the temporary table that contains the data to replace.

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47637/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this user-defined function:

http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php#PREG_REPLACE_SECTION

or https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

And rewrite your query to:

```
UPDATE table
SET phone = PREG_REPLACE('#[^\d]#', '', phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, multiple calls to your database incurs a speed hit, and (in my experience), it's a painful one.  Even two trips to the database can lead to a noticeable delay over one.

To get around this, you want to minimize the calls to your database, which means doing as much in one call as possible.  To this end, try rewriting this as a single SQL update where your replacement logic is in SQL itself.  That would mean only one trip to the database and a massive speed improvement.

That's easier said than done, since last I checked, MySQL didn't have a regular expression string replacement function.  You could try a work-around, or see about some of the UDF's. Another answer provided a link for one.  I recommend looking into that.